# Octave Description of Object

Tags: r, octave

In R the class function returns the description of an object.

```
> a = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow=2, ncol=2) 
> class(a)

[1] "matrix"
```

Is there an equivalent function in octave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` gives you the (atomic) storage type, `typeinfo` gives you the object:

```
>> M = [1 2; 3 4]
M =

   1   2   
   3   4

>> class(M)
ans = double
>> typeinfo(M)
ans = matrix
>>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was executing similar code in MATAB and it returned:
    Undefined function or variable 'typeinfo'.

It works just fine in Octave.

Comment: You are welcome, and thanks for accepting. I just corrected the `M` object to be a 2x2 matrix as I had missed a semicolon.  Feel free to upvote too :)

Comment: I am new to Octave, MATLAB. Up to now, all octave code has run ok in MATLAB. Do you have any idea why typeinfo returns an error in MATLAB.

Comment: @user1254513 Matlab does not have a typeinfo function. Also, Matlab is not a acronym.